In the Alliance-Union universe (C.J. Cherryh, J. Fancher), what explained the Beta Station mystery?
In the Alliance-Union universe (C.J. Cherryh, J. Fancher), what explained the Beta Station mystery?
Some details about the Beta station being abandoned and the missing station personnel are discussed by Galway crew members in the newest duology (Alliance Rising, Alliance Unbound)... I am seeking details of mining operations nearby which were damaged and/or have impacted the exterior of Beta station.
